# How to make a discord music bot play a youtube link?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a music bot in Javascript and I'm trying to figure out how to make it play a link. I've tried a lot of things but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
}

  else if(command === prefix + 'play'){
    const song = message.content.first
     const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    connection.play(ytdl(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-NMn5H4hXU&t=4s, { filter: '' }));
  
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you forget to put quotation marks around your string like this?

```js
connection.play(ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-NMn5H4hXU&t=4s", { filter: '' }));
```

If that does not fix your problem, you can try to use [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core) with [ytdl-core-discord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-discord) if you are not using them already. That's what I use in my bot.

For discord.js 12.x:

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");
/* ... connection defined somewhere ... */
connection.play(await ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-NMn5H4hXU&t=4s"), { type: "opus" });
```

For discord.js 12.x (without await):

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");
/* ... connection defined somewhere ... */
ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-NMn5H4hXU&t=4s").then((stream) => {
    connection.play(stream, { type: "opus" });
});
```

For discord.js 11.4.x:

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");
/* ... connection defined somewhere ... */
connection.playOpusStream(await ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-NMn5H4hXU&t=4s"));
```